# Rails аутентификация

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Хотелось спросить, кто и чем пользуется для проверки авторизации и аутентификации, просто начал искать и наткнулся на много разных гемов (плагинов) для этих действий - хотелось бы знать, какой выбрать (чтобы не ошибиться в изучении).

З.Ы. И сразу, не отходя от кассы, еще один вопросик по другой теме. Про использование ActionMailer...

В

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'mail.your.domain',
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'your.domain',
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => 'username@your.domain',
  :password => 'password'
}
```

есть строчка :domain => ...

Вопрос: сколько я ее ни изменял и ни гуглил, так и не понял, зачем она нужна... могу поставить вообще левые данные и все равно работает, при каких условиях выдаст ошибку и вообще где используется?

Comment: Не поленитесь создать два вопроса!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Аутентификация - [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/)

Авторизация - [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)